# Visual Studio IntelliSense threat not nested namespace as syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I decided to switch from CLion to VS22, I found that the code analyzer swears at the new way of writing namespace, that avoid their nesting. I do not know how to make Visual Studio stop considering this an error, as a compiler I used clang and CMake to build, C++ standard is 23

[image: Sample]

Comment: Does it produce an error when you compile? Or just intellisense?

Comment: Yes, its compiles fine

Comment: Check your Intellisense settings. This syntax was introduced in C++ 17 (IIRC) and I've experienced some weird things in some IDEs and editors where configurations clashed and these things happened

Answer (score 0):

Just for this issue, I suggest you don't use Clang and Cmake, create new project with MSVC and this problem will not occur.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: i dont want to port my whole project from cmake

Comment: @NullifiedVlad Hi, I suggest you select Options in Tools and set Disable Squiggles to true.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrj6h.png